# How to return any of the last Models added to the datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I modify this

```
 videos = Video.gql( 'WHERE user_id = :1', '18' ).fetch(8)
```

so that instead of matching for a user_id, it returns any of the last 8 Video objects added to the datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your models with a

```
created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

for this type of queries.

The accepted answer on this question is not correct. If you add a `created` property to your models and compare queries ordered by `-created` and `-__key__` you will see that they don't match.

Keys that are automatically set will not be monotonically increasing. Some good read on that [here](http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/) .

Comment: Key ID allocation has absolutely nothing to do with splitting entities "over multiple datacenters".

Comment: I think "over multiple datacenters" was not what I meant to say. I'll edit that part out. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be to have a property that store the date created, this would allow you to query a bunch of different queries including last created.

Example

```
class Video(db.Model):
    ...
    user_id = ...
    date_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
```

retrieve last 8 additions:

```
Video.all().order("-date_created").fetch(8)
```

Besides this, you can do more interesting queries by date range an so on.

Hope this helps as well!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Video.gql('ORDER BY __key__ DESC').fetch(8)
```

In fact, you don't need to use `GQL` at all for this:

```
Video.all().order('-__key__').fetch(8)
```

Comment: That's perfect. What does '-__key__' mean though?

Comment: `'-__key__'` means a descending order (hence the `-`) by the key. If you do not specify a custom key, each entity will get a key ID greater than the previous one. Key IDs are 64-bit unsigned integers (well, `long`s). You can get it on any entity like this: `Video.all().get().key().id()`.